# Редирект со страниц одного сайта на страницы другого

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

у меня есть два сайта. К примеру:
old-site.com - старый сайт
new-site.com - новый сайт

Мне нужно перенаправление
с https://old-site.com/growing-guides/post-name/
на https://new-site.com/blogs/growing-guides/post-name

При этом, чтобы не было редиректа на главной странице сайта (с old-site.com на new-site.com)

Подскажите пожалуйста как реализовать это, чтобы не добавлять редирект к каждому посту

Пробовала по этому примеру сделать:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^growing\-guides\/ https://new-site.com/blogs/growing-guides/? [L,R=301]
```

Перенаправление работает частично. Если мне нужно открыть только категорию https://old-site.com/growing-guides/ то оно работает и перенаправляет на https://new-site.com/blogs/growing-guides/.

Но если я хочу зайти на https://old-site.com/growing-guides/post-name/ оно направляет на https://new-site.com/blogs/growing-guides/, вместо нужного https://new-site.com/blogs/growing-guides/post-name

Answer (score 0):

Вот так вроде:

```html
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$
  RewriteRule ^folder(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/folder$1 [R=301,L] 
</IfModule>
```

Но учтите, что post запросы оно будет редиректить без параметров. А просто как замена ссылок (даже с ?a=456&b=678) будет норм.